# How to remove spaces (Only from JSON Keys) from JSON file using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file having key value pairs. Currently I'm using python built in Replace() function to replace spaces with underscore but it also replace spaces with underscore in values.I only want to replace spaces from Keys, Values should remain the same.
This is the python function I'm using

```
string=string.replace(" ","_")
```

Comment: Is `string` an unparsed JSON file?

Comment: Could you sample input json and expected output format to be?

Comment: @mousetail yes string is unparsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the keys. What you can do is add the modified key, value pair and then remove the old one.

Let's say you have a dictionary like below:

```
{'x c': 'z c'}
```

You can write following script to replace whitespaces in keys:

```
x = {"x c":"z c"}
for key,value in x.iteritems():
    new_key = key.replace(" ","_")
    del x[key] # Deleting Previous Key
    x[new_key] = value # Adding Modified key
```

Output:

```
{'x_c': 'z c'}
```

*Hope this helps you out!!!*

Answer (score 5):

The assumption I am working under is that you first convert the Json string to a dictionary. Then:

The most *pythonic* (idiomatic, clearest and efficient) way to do this is with a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
d = {"key 1": "Value 1", "key 2": "value 2"}
new_d = {k.replace(" ", "_"): v for k, v in d.items()}
print(new_d)
```

Prints:

```
{'key_1': 'Value 1', 'key_2': 'value 2'}
```

`d.items()` iterates all the key/value pairs of the dictionary as variables `k` and `v` in the above code and after the spaces are replaced with underscores in `k`, a new dictionary is created from these `k` and `v` pairs.

You can then convert the dictionary back to a Json string.